# How to render ->

Tags: symbols

I tried to render the arrow symbol `->` using `\->`, but it didn't work. I tried `\-\>` as well, which didn't work either. Both compiled well but didn't generate the right symbol. I suspect it might be encoding problem.

Comment: `\textrightarrow` in text and `\rightarrow`/`\to` in math. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Look at the link [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/Symbols.pdf) on the section for arrows for finding the answer you're looking for.

Comment: If you are trying to get a "ascii drawn arrow", such as the ones used in C to dereference pointers to structures, you can try `\verb|->|`. For mathematical uses better to use `$\to$` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use the arrow from the math environment: `$ \rightarrow $`